# CSS - Separate inner <div>'s into columns depending on viewport

Tags: html, css

I have the following example HTML:

```
<div class="vini">
  <!-- div of class "vino" can be 1 or also 100 times rendered, one below another just like this: -->
  <div class="vino">
  <div class="vino">
  <div class="vino">
  <div class="vino">
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve the following:

**Scenario for PC:**
All the `<div class="vino">` should be somehow adjusted to display always only 3 of these `divs` in a row (from left to right). Then, in the next row, there should be the next 3 of these `divs`, and so on until there is no more left.

**Scenario for Mobile:**
All the `<div class="vino">` should be visible one below another - make them scrollable from up all the way down until there are no more of these `divs` to be shown.

I have tried playing around with `display: flex` CSS property but I was not able to get it done.

Ideally, I would like to get this done via CSS and HTML only (no JS).

Any ideas how shall I do this, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following styles will get you close to what you need.

The **.vini** styles will make that container, and it's children into flexed items.

The **.vino** styles will make the items take up **100% width** then at screen **width: 768px**, will make them take up **32% width** to give them a little breathing space between each item (as 100 / 3 = 33.3% repeating)

```
.vini {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.vino {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .vino {
    flex:0 0 32%;
    max-width:32%;
  }
}
```

Comment: you could also use the `gap` property. However a grid might be more appropiate for that sue case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only creates 1 column per row on my PC screen (full HD resolution, maximized window)

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work fine on JSFiddle, but it does not work in WordPress. Interesting..

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one as it seems to be a problem with WordPress overwriting my CSS. Thank you!